# VBA: Remove everything after (and including) a specific character

Tags: vba, excel

I'm have a column with cells containing data like:

```
PY=486776347 PY 7031493729
```

I'm trying to dynamically remove everything after and including the space in this instance, but it'd be useful to know how to do this for any character.

I tried this, with no success:

```
Columns("P:P").Replace What:=" ""*", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart
```

and

```
[P:P].Replace What:=" ""*", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart 'should be effectively the same function as above
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to add (`&`) like:

```
Columns("P:P").Replace What:=" " & "*", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart
```

Or :

```
Columns("P:P").Replace What:=" *", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart
```

We can replace the space with any character, for example `3`:

```
Columns("P:P").Replace What:="3*", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart
```

The result is: `PY=486776`

Comment: Perfect, thorough answer. Thank you! Though, out of curiosity, what if I wanted to remove everything after the second space instead?

Comment: @Dr.Trey, You are welcome, if all data in this format (there is `PY` before the second space) we can use `Columns("P:P").Replace What:="PY *", Replacement:="PY", LookAt:=xlPart`. and if not maybe we need to use loop `For Each Cell In range`.